# How to initialize a struct with union?

Tags: c++, visual-c++

How can I properly initialize a struct which contains a union? Currently I get an error `// error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'float' to 'const char *'`

```
#include <stdio.h>

using namespace std;

typedef enum {STRING, REAL, POINTER } Type;

const struct Entry {
    union {
        const char *string;
        float real;
        void *pointer;
    };
    Type type;
    LPCSTR Key;
    LPCSTR Name;
}f;

const Entry Entries[] = {
    {{0.5f}, REAL, "Key", "Name" } // error C2440: 'initializing': cannot convert from 'float' to 'const char *'
};

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < size(Entries); i++)
    {
        switch Entries[i].type
        {
            case STRING:
                printf("Type string; Value: %s\n", Entries[i].string);
            case REAL:
                printf("Type string; Value: %d\n", Entries[i].real);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi, welcome to SO! You tagged this [tag:C++] but to me this is just plain [tag:C], no?

Comment: @kebs Except that `using namespace std;` part, and using `Entry` as a type.

Comment: Yep, sure. But thats about it, really a strong "C" smell (stdio.h, printf, ...)

Comment: @kebs - Bar the initialization and missing windows header, this is mostly valid C++. Our ideas of how "real" C++ looks are neither here nor there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When initializing a union, only the *first* member will be initialized. Rearrange the union so that `float real` becomes the first member of the union.

Of course, that means you can't use the other members in direct initialization.

The other solution is to add a constructor to the union, like one for the `real` member, one for the `string` member and one for the `pointer` member.

Comment: Constructor could actually be a fine solution. Hmm.

Comment: In C++20, `{ .real = 0.5f }` could come in handy for this

Comment: @user10926577 until c++20 it's a gcc extension which is also implemented in clang.

Comment: Heh. Another reason NOT to use MSVC.

Answer (score 0):

What is the reason You want to use union? Unions are great for saving memory. In c++ rarely there is a need to use them.
I know that is not the answer for your question but think if You have to use them in this project.